# Javascript changing innerHTML to a different pages content not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT SOLVED:

Below works great.  The suggested link marking this a duplicate does not solve the problem.
     `changeDrinks.innerHTML = '< object type="text/html" data="drinks.html" >  </object > ";`

What is wrong with my javascript below?

**JS :**

```
var changeDrinks = document.querySelector("#menuDropWine");
changeDrinks.innerHTML = 'drinks.html';
```

I wanted this to change the content of a div to drinks.html webpage. The div's content that is being changed looks like this...

```
<div id="menuDropWine" class="divBtn">
```

I've read a couple questions on here already about changing the content of a div.  Some used ajax, others used jQuery, but I feel I should be able to just use innerHTML equals a link.  Currently this is just changing my div's content to the literal text output of 'drinks.html'.  I hope I'm just missing an a href reference or something, as I feel this solution should be simple.  The only real reason I want to put this into my website is so it cleans the looks of my index.html to not have so much text content, by storing the text content in different links that just load on a click.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, just because you 'feel' it should be one way it does not mean it is supposed to be that way.  When you use `innerHTML`, you are supposed to pass (as string/text) the actual `HTML` (i.e. tags) that make up the internal 'HTML' of the element you are modifying.  Indeed, it could be `HTML` coming from another page (like `drinks.html`) but you need to load that page first (from the server or current location) and then pass the loaded page as string to the method.  The way to load that page is via ajax (or using JQuery to bypass all the different ways to do ajax depending on browsers, etc)

Comment: So like jQuery load method?  I tried that first.  $('#menuDropWine').load(which + 'drinks.html'); but it didn't end up working.

Comment: did you add the library to your page before using it? - also keep in mind that it works from a server (JS does not have access to your file system for security reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the function of `innerHTML`; it accepts a string of HTML, creates the required DOM structure and injects it into the the target element. The easiest way to achieve what you want is with an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), setting its `src` property to 'drinks.html'.

```
<iframe src="drinks.html" frameborder="0">Your browser doesn't support iframes</iframe>
```

Assuming that drinks.html is a full HTML document (has an `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tag), this is really the best route. If drinks.html is a partial HTML document then you could look into using AJAX. I would suggest using jQuery and then you could easily do something like:

```
$('#menuDropWine').load('drinks.html');
```

Comment: I actually got my above code to work by adding this       changeDrinks.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="drinks.html" ></object>';   The only problem with it is that the format is entirely off from the div size.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is that the element will be filled with the text `drinks.html`, which is not incorrect, but obviously not what you had in mind.

JavaScript is not psychic, so it doesn’t know whether you want to change the content or load from an external document, so this behaviour is perfectly natural.

If you want a simple solution, use an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), whose `src` attribute can be set in JavaScript as follows:

```
var changeDrinks = document.getElementById("menuDropWine");
changeDrinks.src = 'drinks.html';
```

BTW note that if you know you are using an `id`, it is more efficient to use `document.getElementById`.

If you really want to use `innerHTML`, as the others have commented, you will have to use Ajax. A simple example, without jQuery, follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=init;
            function init() {
                var test=document.getElementById('test');
                var url='test.html';
                load(test,url);
            }
            function load(element,url) {
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('get', url, true);
                xhr.send(null);
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (this.readyState==4) {
                        element.innerHTML=this.responseText;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div id="test">Hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here, `test.html` is expected to have your new content.